# Prevent iOS podcast syncing of position and played status

Tags: ios, podcasts

We are two people with two iPhones that share one Apple ID. We individually listen to some of the same podcasts on each iPhone. The "played" status and current position of the podcast episodes appear to get sync'ed between the phones at least some of the time. We don't want this to happen.

1. Settings -> Podcasts -> Sync Podcasts is OFF on both phones.
2. We both sync with iTunes regularly to update apps, music, etc., but podcast syncing is turned OFF for both phones on iTunes (Windows).

Can we prevent played and position status of podcast episodes from syncing so we can each listen independently to the episodes? Or is sync'ing unavoidable? One solution is probably to get a second Apple ID, but I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such bugs with Apple Podcasts have been known for a while. The best solution (like you mentioned) is probably to get another Apple ID. With the new family feature, you can share purchases and Apple Music subscriptions across Apple IDs. If this idea still doesn't appeal to you, try a third-party podcast program, like this one: http://vemedio.com/products/instacast